# Bayesian Parameter Estimation - Parameters and Data Jointly Continuous?

Tags: probability, bayesian

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356782/bayes-rule-for-parameter-estimation-parameters-are-random-variables) regarding viewing parameters as random variables in a Bayesian framework.

If we apply Bayes' theorem to model parameters $\mathbf{\Theta} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and data $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ we get
$$
g(\boldsymbol\theta|\mathbf{y}) = \frac{h(\mathbf{y}|\boldsymbol\theta) g(\boldsymbol\theta)}{h(\mathbf{y})},
$$
where $g$ is the marginal pdf of $\mathbf{\Theta}$, $h$ is the marginal pdf of $\mathbf{Y}$ and $g(\cdot|\mathbf{y})$, $h(\cdot|\boldsymbol\theta)$ are the respective conditional pdfs.  I call $g$ and $h$ the marginal pdfs because I am assuming we are viewing the random vectors $\mathbf{\Theta}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ as jointly continuous, and hence have a joint pdf $f(\boldsymbol\theta, \mathbf{y})$.

Is this necessary to assume?  I.e., when using Bayes' rule above, it seems like I only need to assume that the collection $\{\Theta_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is jointly continuous and that the collection $\{Y_j\}_{j=1}^m$ is jointly continuous, but not necessarily both collections together.  In this case $g$ would just be considered the joint pdf of $\{\Theta_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $h$ the joint pdf of $\{Y_j\}_{j=1}^m$, rather than the marginals of the individual random vectors.  Is this correct?

Comment: In practice, $g(\theta)$ is the prior density and $h(y|\theta)$ is the likelihood (pdf of $y$ parameterized by $\theta$ considered as a function of $\theta$ for known data $y$). If it is possible to use conjugate prior and likelihood (known up to a constant), then one can usually replace $=$ by $\propto$ ('proportional to') and avoid integrating the denominator $\int h(y|\theta)g(\theta)\,d\theta$.In some applications, such as estimating population size, $\theta$ is discrete. Data $y$ may be discrete or continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulation of independence seems to ignore the crucial conditional relationships. Also your interpretation concentrates
on continuous distributions, whereas some applications use a mixture
of discrete and continuous distributions. Furthermore, your
statement of Bayes' theorem ignores the usual practice of
specifying the likelihood function only up to a constant.

**Bayes' Theorem applied to inference.** Perhaps an applied example will be useful. Suppose our data
is the number of counts recorded by a Geiger counter during
a certain period of time. Typically, such counts are modeled
as a Poisson random variable $Y \sim Pois(\theta),$ where we
wish to find an interval estimate for the unknown mean $\theta$
of the Poisson distribution. One might write

$$h(y|\theta) = \frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^y}{y!} \propto
 \theta^ye^{-\theta},$$

using $\propto$ to indicate that the factor $1/y!$ is suppressed.

**Likelihood function** Here we are viewing $h(y|\theta)$ as a likelihood function of
$\theta$ for known data $y,$ and the suppressed factor is not
relevant to our inference.

**Prior distribution.** A Bayesian approach to this estimation problem is to
begin with a prior distribution $\theta \sim Gamma(\alpha, \kappa),$
where $\alpha$ is the shape parameter and $\kappa$ is the
rate parameter. One might write

$$g(\theta) \propto \theta^{\alpha-1}e^{-\kappa\theta},$$

again using $\propto$ instead of $=$ to signal
suppression of an unnecessary factor, the constant of integration.
If expert opinion or prior information suggests that $\theta \approx 12$ and  $\theta > 25$ is unlikely, then we might choose $\alpha = 4$
and $\kappa = 1/3$ because $Gamma(4, 1/3)$ has mean $\mu = 12$
and puts only about 3% of its probability beyond 25. (If we had
little prior information, we might pick smaller values for $\alpha$ and $\kappa.$)

**Posterior distribution.** Suppose our observation turns out to be $y = 8$ counts. Multiplying the prior by the likelihood we have the posterior
distribution given by

$$g(\theta|y) \propto g(\theta)h(y|\theta) = 
\theta^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\kappa\theta} \times
\theta^ye^{-\theta} = 
\theta^{(4+8)-1}e^{1(1/3+1)\theta},$$
which we recognize as the 'kernel' of $Gamma(12,4/3);$
that is, the density function without its constant of integration.

Because the gamma and Poisson distributions are 'conjugate'
(mathematically compatible in a convenient way), we did not
need to evaluate the denominator $h(y) = \int h(y|\theta)g(\theta)\,d\theta$ of your formula for
Bayes' Theorem.

**Estimation: Posterior mean and probability interval.** The posterior mean is $12/(4/3) = 9$ and a 95% posterior
interval estimate of $\theta$ is $(4.65, 14.76)$ [Obtained in R,
using `qgamma(c(.025,.975), 12. 4/3)`].

Note: A frequentist
95% CI using the formula $Y+2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{Y+1}$ is
$(4.12, 15.88)$. Thus our mildly informative prior
has not had huge influence over the numerical values
of the endpoints of the interval estimate. To the
extent that the information contained in the prior
distribution is applicable, the Bayesian estimate
is superior.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Would you elaborate why the likelihood function $h$ is viewed as a conditional pdf?  I.e., If you were to ask me to write down the Poisson pdf, I would write $h(y) = \frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^y}{y!}$ or perhaps $h(y;\theta) = \frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^y}{y!}$; but if you asked me for the conditional pdf I would write $h(y|\theta) = \frac{f(\theta,y)}{g(\theta)}$ for joint pdf $f$ and marginal pdf $g$...not what you have.

Comment: @bcf:  As a Poisson cdf (or pmf) for finding probabilities of outcomes, given $\theta = 5,$ it's $P(X = y) = e^{-\theta}\theta^y/y!$, for $y = 0, 1, 2, \dots.$ So $P(X = y) = e^{-5}5^y/y!$. As a likelihood function given $y=3$ to estimate unknown $\theta$ its $h(3|\theta) = e^{-\theta}\theta^3 /3!$ $\propto e^{-\theta} \theta^3.$ For example, term $1/3!$ (constant in $\theta$) is not relevant to maximizing the likelihood function in $\theta$ to find $\hat \theta$ the MLE of $\theta.$ The integral for the denominator of Bayes Theorem $h(y)$ given in my Answer is a _constant_ when $y$ is known.

Comment: I understand the denominator is constant; I was referring to your first equation.  Is it that, for Bayesian inference, we *redefine* the pdf to be not even a conditional pdf, but a function of the parameter(s)?  Then, in our case, the "likelihood" function is the pdf defined as, for fixed $y$, the mapping $\theta \mapsto h(y|\theta)$?

Comment: I suppose you can look at it that way. But the crucial point is that Bayesian inference takes place after data are observed. You might say the only remaining probability distributions involve the parameter(s).