# Estimate the parameters of the Laplacian distribution using Bayesian Distribution

Tags: bayesian, artificial-intelligence

I have the following zero-mean Laplacian distribution, and I am trying to estimate its parameters using Bayesian Estimation.

[image: Laplacian Distribution]

Comment: Can you write down the Likelihood function in terms of the parameter $b$ and the data $x_{1}$, $\ldots$, $x_{n}$?  What would you do next?

Comment: To speak about Bayesian estimation, you should have a prior distribution of a parameter $b$. What is it? What $\omega_1$ means here?

Answer (score 0):

Using maximum likelihood estimation with data $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$, [parameter estimation for the Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) $\mathcal{L}(\mu,b)$ can be done by $\hat{\mu}=\text{median}\left(\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n\right)$ and
$$ \hat{b} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i |x_i - \hat{\mu}| $$
where in your case you can simply assume $\mu=0$ (and so $\hat{\mu}=0$).

However, if you want do *Bayesian* parameter estimation, rather than the frequentist style, you need to make some assumptions: specifically a loss function and a prior distribution for $b$.

See some of the following:

- [How to choose a prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78606/how-to-choose-prior-in-bayesian-parameter-estimation),
- [Parameters as random variables in Bayesian estimation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356782/bayes-rule-for-parameter-estimation-parameters-are-random-variables),
- [Questions on continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356873/bayesian-parameter-estimation-parameters-and-data-jointly-continuous)
- [Intuition for parameter distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115009/how-does-one-interpret-the-distribution-over-parameters-in-bayesian-estimation?rq=1)
- [Comparison to frequentist outlook](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31867/bayesian-vs-frequentist-interpretations-of-probability?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- Some examples/related questions: 
  [[1]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69383/estimating-the-parameter-of-a-uniform-distribution-improper-prior), 
  [[2]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87110/why-is-it-that-it-is-self-defeating-to-use-the-posterior-mode-as-the-bayes-estim?noredirect=1&lq=1), 
  [[3]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31142/estimation-of-parameters-as-a-mode-of-posterior-distribution)